# How to get strings of text in VB.net and check to see if Regex found the string of text?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string containing a sequence of SHA512 virus hashes. I want to match against this string to detect whether or not an input is malicious. How can I use Regex to find items in this string and save it to a new string value? This is what I have so far:

```
Dim SHA512Hash = Regex.Match(str, SHA512virushash)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex.Match returns a [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.8) object. The Match object contains both the [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Capture_Value) property and [Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Group_Captures) property, the former contains the matched substring whereas the latter contains a collection of matched substrings.

Depending on what you are expecting, you will want to either get the match from your `SHA512Hash` variable by getting the value of the Value property *or* you will want to iterate through every match by getting the value of the Captures property and then get the currently iterated match's value.

Comment: OK thanks, but I want to compare the SHA512 hash with the ones in TextBox2, which is hidden

Comment: Compare the value you get from the Match object to `TextBox2.Text`